# Why I am getting an error with a function is almost same with the other, but at bottom of it?

Tags: python-3.x, function

Can someone teach me how to make a script part in body?

```
def tahtaDoldu():
    mu = 0
    for i in hamle:
        if i != " ":
            mu += 1
        if mu > 0:
            return True
        else: return False
```

`hamle` is a list defined earlier. All spaces are given with tab and I corrected them a few times. When I run it, it gives a

> SyntaxError: expected an indented block

And the empty line after the ":" on function's line turns to red. What is the problem here?

Comment: Please edit your question to show the exact indentation in your code.. but if  that's the problem then I suggest you check through the indentation yourself and see what you've missed.

Comment: You posted a blob of text, with code with no formatting or indentation mixed with your text before and after. How do you expect us to help you with an **expected an indented block** error from that? In addition, the text in your title doesn't even parse as an actual sentence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you either use spaces or tabs for indentation, your code is fine, just make sure your `hamle` list is either passed to the function.

e.g.

```
def tahtaDoldu(hamle):

    mu = 0
    for i in hamle:
        if i != " ":
            mu += 1
        if mu > 0:
            return True
        else: 
            return False
```